# BiHiSankey diagram in iframe with a dynamic size

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, svg, sankey-diagram

I am working on Bi-directional hierarchical sankey diagram (http://bl.ocks.org/Neilos/584b9a5d44d5fe00f779).

I have added more than 50 nodes now and the diagram height is not fitting the page.

I am also using the sankey.html on another page inside an ifame and it is not fitting there also. But when I change the height of iframe to for example height:2000px and make svg style height:100%, weight:100% it works perfectly and shows all nodes without problem.

I do not want to give a constant height to the iframe though. Because I have buttons which uploads different node and link files and visualize them in same iframe. So the width of the iframe should be dynamic.

I have come accross this answer ([Increasing d3 SVG container size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36650068/increasing-d3-svg-container-size)) but couldn't solve my problem, I do not know why :( and unfortunately I can not comment to ask details.

Anyone who has an idea how can I solve this issue?

Thank you in advance for the support!